# SiteCore include third party html files within page structure

Tags: sitecore

Using SiteCore 6.5, we have a need to include a set of html files (there are many) within our site. They need to use the same header and footer as other pages within our site.

We don't want to use iFrames.

The wildcard module (http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Wildcard_module.aspx) has been suggested to us but is there anything else quick and easy we could use without the drawbacks of iFrames???

Comment: What so you intend the end URL structure to be like? Multiple folders deep? How are the files organised currently? What does your HTML contain? Head, body, script tags? Current header/footers that you need to remove before inserting into the Sitecore rendering?

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a sublayout and itemresolver/wildcard.

- The sublayout (cached, offcourse) would load the html file from disk and parse the html, strip headers and footers (use HTMLAgilityFramework). Optionally you could rewrite the href's.
- The ItemResolver/wildcards would map the incoming url to the correct path to use.

easy peasy.

Recommended however is importing the content (this will give you the Sitecore benifits). This can be done by the design imported, possible together with custom import logic (which would use the HTMLAgilityFramework).

Comment: I find HAP a little fiddly, esp if you are are used to jQuery. Check out [FizzlerEx](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/) and [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery), but the end result is the same :)

Comment: Thanks jammykan, i'll do that.